# preserve key if possible while inserting into database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write a method that will import data into database from CSV preserving primary key if possible. That means, it will insert record with same key if that key does not exist in DB already, otherwise will insert the record with new key.

To do that, I wrote below code which is working per plan. However, I am getting Error of "PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)" in LogCat every time a key is duplicated (which is understandable).

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any better way to do the same?
2. If not, is there any way I can suppress those errors in logCat?
3. Are those error logs going to cause any performance issue, or should I just ignore them?

My CODE:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result); // whole JSON Array of data
String[] data;
int cnt;
long flag=0;
mylibmandbhandler db = new mylibmandbhandler(context); //db class
int maxlength = jArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < maxlength; i++) {
    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    cnt = 0;
    dataline = new String[3];
    dataline[cnt++] = json.getString("bookid"); //PRIMARY KEY
    dataline[cnt++] = json.getString("bookname");
    dataline[cnt++] = json.getString("writer");
    flag = db.addRecord(new mylibman(dataline)); //ADDS RECORD USING db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    if(flag==-1){
        dataline[0]="-1"; // IF PRIMARY KEY EXISTS MAKE BOOKID = -1, WHICH WILL IGNORE BOOKID IN db.addRecord METHOD
        db.addRecord(new mylibman(dataline));
    }
}
db.close();
```

**db.addRecord**

```
public long addRecord(mylibman mylibman) { //mylibman is custom class
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if(mylibman.getBookid() != -1){
        values.put(KEY_ID, mylibman.getBookid());
    }
    values.put(KEY_NAME, mylibman.getBookname());
    values.put(KEY_WRITER, mylibman.getWriter());
    // Inserting Row
    long numrow = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    return numrow;
}
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at com.migrationdesk.mylibman.mylibmandbhandler.addRecord(mylibmandbhandler.java:106)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at com.migrationdesk.mylibman.MyImportServiceClass$RemoteConnectivity.doInBackground(MyImportServiceClass.java:281)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at com.migrationdesk.mylibman.MyImportServiceClass$RemoteConnectivity.doInBackground(MyImportServiceClass.java:1)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-03 03:50:26.557: E/SQLiteDatabase(1509):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: primaryKey must be unique => why not just update entry if id exists in db?

Comment: just for example, let say I have 2 libraries, I want to merge them together. So, I want to import all book records of Library 2 into Library 1. While importing, if any book of Library 2 has same bookID as an existing book of Library 1, then give a new ID during import, otherwise give the same old ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to write a method that will import data into database from CSV preserving primary key if possible. That means, it will insert record with same key if that key does not exist in DB already, otherwise will insert the record with new key.

I'd suggest you create new primary keys and preserve the old key in another non-unique column. I don't see much benefit of preserving an id that you don't really know is preserved, and the auto-generated ids will likely generate further conflicts.

Other than that, some improvements to the current approach:

1. Don't open and close the database in `addRecord()`. Instead, open the database outside the `for` loop and close it after it, passing the reference to the `addRecord()` method.
2. Bundle up multiple inserts (let's say 1000) in a single database transaction instead of doing each insert in a separate implicit transaction. This has huge impact on reducing I/O and therefore improving performance.
3. The exceptions you get will bubble up to a higher level catch block. Your recovery logic won't work since the loop is no longer running. Instead you could specify an SQL conflict resolution strategy (other than throwing), e.g.

   ```
   db.insertWithOnConflict(... , SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
   ```

Comment: huge thanks for detail and to the point answers, and additional recommendations ... I'll implement all of these ....

Comment: just one thing, for point 2, I need to insert with rawQuery method if I want to insert in bunch, am I correct? Or can use db.insert method to insert multiple rows simultaneously?

Comment: No. `db.insert()` works perfectly well with transactions. Use `rawQuery()` only for operations that return a result you want to iterate over (`SELECT`s and so on).

Answer (score 0):

so check if that id exists, if it does make a new insert without id, assuming your primary key is set to autoincrement, it will generate a new id for the given object, or if id is still free just insert it?

anything i missed?

so, get a list with all ids that are currently in db, if list contains current id, insert without id, else insert with id. make it a batch and performance should be fine.

Comment: yaa, id is auto_increment field. Actually I implemented your process at the beginning. But in that process, for each book (let say I am importing 1000 books), I have to make query to database twice - 1st to check whether the ID exists, then to insert the new book ... is it better or my current process is better (where we have to run 1 query for new Ids, and 2 queries for duplicated ids)?